# Webアプリの変数だけを持ってくる方法を知りたいです。

Tags: python, java

現在パイソンでTwitterのアカウントがbotであるかどうかを調べる。というプログラムを書いているのですが、そこでbot or notというWebアプリを見つけました。pythonをつかい自動操作で処理を行いそのページからbot判定度を変数として持ってきたいのですが、良い方法はないでしょうか？

こちらが件のサイトです。bot判定度というのはアカウント名を入れると出てくる23%などの数値のことです。
https://botometer.iuni.iu.edu/#!/

Answer (score 1):

当該サービスの場合であれば[Web APIが公開されてい](https://botometer.iuni.iu.edu/#!/api)、[公式のPythonクライアント](https://github.com/IUNetSci/botometer-python)も用意されているようです。

これらのページを参考にこのAPIを利用されればいかがでしょうか。